# Python: remove empty lists from within comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am implementing dijkstras algorithm to compute shortest path.  My question is just if there is a cleaner way to implement the following comprehension (i.e without `if [b for a,b in G[x] if a not in X]!=[]]` tacked onto the end).

In the following, G is a graph where its keys are the graphs nodes, and each node has a list of tuples representing its connecting edges.  So each tuple contains the information: (connected node, distance to connected node). X is a set of nodes that the algorithm has already looked at, and A is dictionary mapping those nodes that have already been found to the shortest distance to them from the starting node, in this case node 1.

UPDATE: sorry i gave an example that worked, here is one that does not work if the last part of the comprehension is removed.

```
G = {1: [(2, 20), (3, 50)], 2: [(3, 10), (1, 32)], 3: [(2, 30), (4, 10)], 4: [(1, 60)]}
X = {1,2,3}
A = {1: 0, 2: 20, 3:30}

mindist = min([A[x] + min([b for a,b in G[x] if a not in X]) for x in X if [b for a,b in G[x] if a not in X]!=[]])
```

The question is how to write mindist as a comprehension that can deal with taking `min([[],[some number],[])`.

The last part, 
`if [b for a,b in G[x] if a not in X]!=[]]`
just removes the empty lists so min doesnt fail, but is there a better way to write that
comprehension so there are no empty lists.

Comment: empty list evaluates to False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
minval = [float('+inf')]
min(A[x] + min([b for a, b in G[x] if a not in X] + minval) for x in X)
=> 40
```

The trick? making sure that the innermost `min()` always has a value to work with, even if it's a dummy: a positive infinite, because anything will be smaller than it. In this way, the outermost `min()` will ignore the `inf` values (corresponding to empty lists) when computing the minimum.

Comment: going with this answer for its simplicity :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the empty list is considered false in a boolean, so you don't need to test for inequality against `[]`; `if [b for a,b in G[x] if a not in X]` is enough.

What you really want to do is to produce the inner list *once*, then both test and calculate the minimum in one go. Do this with an extra inner 'loop':

```
mindist = min(A[x] + min(inner) 
              for x in X 
              for inner in ([b for a,b in G[x] if a not in X],) if inner)
```

The `for inner over (...,)` loop iterates over a one-element tuple that produces the list *once*, so that you can then test if it is empty (`if inner`) before then calculating the `A[x] + min(inner)` result to be passed to the *outer* `min()` call.

Note that You do not need a list comprehension for that outer loop; this is a generator expression instead, saving you building up a list object that is then discarded again.

Demo:

```
>>> G = {1: [(2, 20), (3, 50)], 2: [(3, 10), (1, 32)], 3: [(2, 30), (4, 10)], 4: [(1, 60)]}
>>> X = {1,2,3}
>>> A = {1: 0, 2: 20, 3:30}
>>> min(A[x] + min(inner) 
...               for x in X 
...               for inner in ([b for a,b in G[x] if a not in X],) if inner)
40
```

Comment: Interesting, so the `if inner` is all that is needed to remove []?  I don't think I understand how generators work.

Comment: @noah: an empty list is falsey in a boolean context. The `!= []` is redundant anywhere, not just in generator expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had to unpack that nutty list comprehension to figure out what you were talking about - I think this is approximately the same code:

```
dists = []
for x in X:
    newdists = [b for a,b in G[x] if a not in X]
    if len(newdists) > 0
        dists.append(A[x] + min(newdists))
mindist = min(dists)
```

Here's an approach that eliminates the test in question:

```
import sys

def newMin(values):
    if len(values) == 0:
        return float('inf')
    else:
        return min(values)

mindist = min(A[x] + newMin([b for a,b in G[x] if a not in X]) for x in X)

print mindist
```

output:

```
40
```

Comment: This could cause your algorithm to fail for cases where some calculated paths have a length greater than sys.maxint, so maybe not the best solution.

Comment: `min(A[x] + min([b for a,b in G[x] if a not in X] or [float('inf')]) for x in X)` :)

Comment: Good idea - I'll incorporate that in place of sys.maxint.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a full solution, but since you're just getting rid of empty lists, you could shorten the condition. An empty list is evaluated as False. A list with anything in it is evaluated as true. Just provide the list as the condition. This is true for all empty built-in data types.